# Local notification delegate methods not invoked after app termination

Tags: swift, localnotification, usernotifications

I'm able to generate local notification after termination however, I'm unable to set a value in didReceive method of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.

Following is my code in AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let keyForTappingNotification = "notification_tapped"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Requesting Authorization for User Interactions
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

        }

        return true
    }

}
```

And following is my code in ViewController:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,willPresent notification: UNNotification,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping(UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler( [.alert,.sound,.badge])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    preferences.set("yes", forKey: self.keyForTappingNotification)
    preferences.synchronize()

    completionHandler()
}
```

And ViewdidLoad goes as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let notification_tapped = self.preferences.string(forKey: self.keyForTappingNotification) {

            if notification_tapped.lowercased() == "yes"{
                //call to specific function which never gets called as values don't match
            }

        }
}
```

The delegate method receives the response only when app is in foreground or background, but not after termination.

Is there a way to receive the response after app termination?